# BDD Jbehave stories while executing results in Pending

Tags: maven, bdd, jbehave

Recently I started working on BDD using JBehave.
    So far if I run using maven, my maven project is getting successfully build. And then its coming into the story file but then its not proceeding further.

I tried by running with junit but I am getting the same result..

I think my problem is with executor file.
    I searched in many sites and even Jbehave.org and many stackoverflow queries..But in vain
    Help me to come out of this problem...Let me know if you need any additional information

```
I spent so much time rectifying this.But couldn't able to find the solution.
Here is my runner file..
package runnerFile;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.jbehave.core.configuration.Configuration;
import org.jbehave.core.configuration.MostUsefulConfiguration;
import org.jbehave.core.io.CodeLocations;
import org.jbehave.core.io.LoadFromClasspath;
import org.jbehave.core.io.StoryFinder;
import org.jbehave.core.junit.JUnitStories;
import org.jbehave.core.junit.JUnitStory;
import org.jbehave.core.reporters.Format;
import org.jbehave.core.reporters.StoryReporterBuilder;
import org.jbehave.core.steps.InjectableStepsFactory;
import org.jbehave.core.steps.InstanceStepsFactory;
import org.jbehave.core.steps.ScanningStepsFactory;
import org.jbehave.core.steps.Steps;


public class TestRunner extends JUnitStories{ 
    @Override
    public Configuration configuration() { 
        return new MostUsefulConfiguration()                
                .useStoryLoader(
                        new LoadFromClasspath(this.getClass().getClassLoader()))
                .useStoryReporterBuilder(
                        new StoryReporterBuilder()
                            .withDefaultFormats()
                            .withFormats(Format.HTML, Format.CONSOLE)
                            .withRelativeDirectory("jbehave-report")
                );
    }

    @Override
    public InjectableStepsFactory stepsFactory() {
      //  ArrayList<Object> stepFileList = new ArrayList<Object>();
        ArrayList<Steps> stepFileList = new ArrayList<Steps>();
       stepFileList.add(new Steps(configuration()));
       return new InstanceStepsFactory(configuration(), stepFileList);
        //return new ScanningStepsFactory(configuration(), "org.jbehave.examples.core.steps", "my.other.steps"`enter code here` ).matchingNames(".*Steps").notMatchingNames(".*SkipSteps");     
    }

    @Override
    protected List<String> storyPaths() {
       return new StoryFinder().
               findPaths(CodeLocations.codeLocationFromClass(
                       this.getClass()), 
                       Arrays.asList("**/TC_2.story"), 
                       Arrays.asList(""));
}
}




I kept my story file inside src/test/resources . and step definition inside src/test/java

****story:****

**src/test/resources**

Narrative:
In order to communicate effectively to the business some functionality
As a development team
I want to use Behaviour-Driven Development

Scenario:  A scenario is a collection of executable steps of different type
Given I launch the url
When I login with username <Username> and password <Password>
Then I should see the homepage

Examples:
|Username|Password|
|test@gmail.com|test1234|

**stepDefinition**

**src/test/java:**


package definition;

import org.jbehave.core.annotations.Given;
import org.jbehave.core.annotations.Named;
import org.jbehave.core.annotations.Then;
import org.jbehave.core.annotations.When;

import pages.Homepage_Pages;

public class HomePage {

    Homepage_Pages home;

    @Given("I launch the url")
    public void url()
    {
        home.launchUrl();
    }

    @When("I login with username <Username> and password <Password>")
    public void login(@Named("Username") String Username, @Named("Password") String Password)
    {
        System.out.println(Username);
    }

    @Then("I should see the homepage")
    public void homePageVerification()
    {
        System.out.println("Heello");
    }
}
```

Maven Console:

[image: Maven COnsole]

Comment: Don't post screenshots of code or console output. They can't be searched so other people with your problem may have trouble finding your question.

Comment: Will follow next time

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code, which is a stripped-down simple testrunner that does nothing fancy, but simply runs all stories found in sub-folders of the main folder, and includes all step classes in the define steps files location.  My original had a lot of those things hard-coded but I changed them to final Strings so it should be easy enough to replace your situation and run with this file.  Obviously, change **"com.yourpackage.steps"** with whatever package folder you place your steps files in.  Hope this helps.

```
package testrunner;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.jbehave.core.configuration.Configuration;
import org.jbehave.core.configuration.MostUsefulConfiguration;
import org.jbehave.core.embedder.EmbedderControls;
import org.jbehave.core.io.CodeLocations;
import org.jbehave.core.io.StoryFinder;
import org.jbehave.core.junit.JUnitStories;
import org.jbehave.core.reporters.CrossReference;
import org.jbehave.core.reporters.Format;
import org.jbehave.core.reporters.StoryReporterBuilder;
import org.jbehave.core.steps.InjectableStepsFactory;
import org.jbehave.core.steps.InstanceStepsFactory;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import de.codecentric.jbehave.junit.monitoring.JUnitReportingRunner;

@RunWith(JUnitReportingRunner.class)
public class TestRunner extends JUnitStories {

    private Configuration configuration;

    public TestRunner() {

        super();

        CrossReference crossReference = new CrossReference();

        configuration = new MostUsefulConfiguration();

        configuration.useStoryReporterBuilder(
                new StoryReporterBuilder().withFormats(Format.HTML, Format.STATS, Format.CONSOLE)
                .withCodeLocation(CodeLocations.codeLocationFromPath("target/."))
                .withCrossReference(crossReference));

        EmbedderControls embedderControls = configuredEmbedder().embedderControls();

        embedderControls.doBatch(false);
        embedderControls.doGenerateViewAfterStories(true);
        embedderControls.doSkip(false);
        embedderControls.doVerboseFailures(true);
        embedderControls.doVerboseFiltering(true);
        embedderControls.useThreads(1);
        embedderControls.useStoryTimeouts("1800");

    }

    @Override
    protected List<String> storyPaths()
    {
        return new StoryFinder().findPaths(CodeLocations.codeLocationFromClass(this.getClass()), "**/*.story", "");
    }

    @Override
    public Configuration configuration() {
        return configuration;
    }

    @Override
    public InjectableStepsFactory stepsFactory() {

        final String stepsPackage = "com.yourpackage.steps";
        final String stepsLoc = "src/test/java/" + stepsPackage.replace(".", "/");

        List<Object> stepList = new ArrayList<Object>();

        File steps = new File(stepsLoc);
        File[] fileList = steps.listFiles();

        int size = fileList.length;

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

            if (fileList[i].isFile()) {                                     // also returns folders (directories)
                String value = fileList[i].getName().replace(".java", "");  // strip extensions
                if (!value.toLowerCase().contains("testrunner")) {          // ignore testrunner itself
                    try {
                        Object stepObject = Class.forName((stepsPackage + "." + value)).newInstance();
                        stepList.add(stepObject);
                    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return new InstanceStepsFactory(configuration(), stepList);
    }

}
```

Comment: Generating reports view to '/Users/334750/eclipse-workspace/Sample/target/jbehave' using formats '[html, stats, console, junitscenarioreporter]' and view properties '{navigator=ftl/jbehave-navigator.ftl, views=ftl/jbehave-views.ftl, reports=ftl/jbehave-reports.ftl, nonDecorated=ftl/jbehave-report-non-decorated.ftl, decorated=ftl/jbehave-report-decorated.ftl, maps=ftl/jbehave-maps.ftl}'
Reports view generated with 0 stories (of which 0 pending) containing 0 scenarios (of which 0 pending)
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Are you running testrunner as a JUnit?  Are your modules, particularly your steps classes, setup in the correct folders?  Are your steps files under a package or unnamed package?  What line and module exactly returns the null pointer exception?  Post the stack trace in your original post.